# Why fiddler displays html content and sometimes not?

Tags: php, localhost, fiddler

I am using fiddler to monitor a simple html content from a php file running in localhost.
But whenever I press f5 to refresh the page (browser), in fiddler sometimes the font of the whole web session turns blue, that is when it actually displays contents(html), the opposite happens when the web session is gray, it does not display html content.

Note: Request/Response headers are always shown, this is just for the content. Also I have tried the dot trick (".:80") and switched from localhost to 127.0.0.1. Also I did not changed any configuration.
By the way, I am using google chrome and it does not even display the web session whenever I create a new Tab & paste the url of the php file.

I don't really know why fiddler works inconsistent on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to display this content in fiddler, the browser cache needs to be cleared.
You can just do a cache refresh with ctrl+f5.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure the server isn't sending back a 304 http response. If it is, you can disable caching by choosing Rules > Performance > Disable Caching.